# Trying to parse items in a list, which are embedded in a web page

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take some data off a intra-net site at work.  I have lots and lots of items in a List; I am trying to parse both of these.

The List looks like this:

```
    var $input = $(".typeahead");
    unique_options_search = new Set([

    "phe_daily_smgm",

    "ex_legacy",

    "dt_legacy",

   etc., etc., etc.

    ]);
```

Is it simply a matter of logging to to the site and fetching that data element?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib.request

REQUEST_URL = 'https://corp-intranet-internal.com/admin/?page=0'
response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=('fname.lname@gmail.com', 'my_pass'))
xml_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(REQUEST_URL)
delay = 5 # seconds
soup = bs(html_page, "lxml")
```

There must be more to it than this, right.  At least, I have to identify that list and parse it, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Is the whole "var $input = ..." part something that's part of the website code itself, in a Javascript function?  Were you able to successfully use BeautifulSoup to extract what you've shown at the top, and now it's just a matter of further extracting what's in the "[ ]" to an actual Python list?

Comment: No, it's not really a subset of anything; it's by itself towards the end of the code on the web page.  It appears to be a list of all the variables in the whole site, that's why I want to get it.  Rather than scrolling through countless URLs, it looks like I can get everything in one spot.  The really weird thing is that when I run the code above, I print(soup) I don't see anything in the console window in Python that matches what I see when I right-click the web page and then click 'View Page Source'.  It's almost like Python is not going to the link I'm telling it to go to.

Comment: `bs(html_page, "lxml")` is going to return a BeautifulSoup object, not a string.   Does `print(html_page)` give you the same thing you see in "View Page Source"?

Comment: Yes, print(html_page) gives me what I want!  I figured it out right now, just as you submitted your answer.  What timing!  How can I get all the items in the 'unique_options_search' list.  I believe that is a list.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this:
all_text = []
soup = bs(html_page, 'lxml')
for link in soup.findAll('unique_options_search'):
    all_text.append(link.get('unique_options_search'))
    print(all_text)

Comment: If you already have the text captured, then at that point on you don't need BeautifulSoup.  I've posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have the top string captured (the whole "var $input ... ]);" thing, and your list is always going to be what's in the brackets, then you could extract what's in the brackets, then break the remainder into a list:

```
import re

mycode = """
    var $input = $(".typeahead");
    unique_options_search = new Set([

    "barra_phe2s_daily_smgm",

    "barra_eue4dukl_monthly_legacy",

    "barra_eue4duk_monthly_legacy",

    "barra_ussc4s_daily_legacy",

    "barra_ussinm1_daily_smgm",

    ]);
"""

inbracks = mycode[mycode.index('[')+1:]
mylist = re.findall(r"['\"](.*?)['\"]", inbracks)
```

I'm sure there's a more complex regular expression you can use that says "Get every string you find within quotation marks, AFTER the first occurrence of '['."  But instead, I just chopped off `mycode` to everything following the first occurrence of the '[' character, then did the `re.findall` on it.

Note that BeautifulSoup lets you parse tag-based things like HTML and XML.  But when it seems something like the code in `mycode`, which is the sort of thing you might find somewhere in a `<script>` tag perhaps, then BeautifulSoup just treats it as "some string".

Comment: Yeah, that basically works.  I'll need to fiddle around with the regex a bit, because it's grabbing a bunch of stuff after the last item in the list, but I can take it for here.  I learned a new trick today!!  Thanks so much Bill M.!!